# Обратный отсчет времени на Js

Tags: javascript

В любом случае данный скрипт выводит Auction is over. Как починить?

```
<div id="clock1"></div>
<script language="JavaScript">
StartCountDown("clock1","20/12/2016 16:00 PM -0400")
function StartCountDown(myDiv,myTargetDate)
{
var dthen   = new Date(myTargetDate);
var dnow    = new Date();
ddiff       = new Date(dthen-dnow);
gsecs       = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
CountBack(myDiv,gsecs);
}
function Calcage(secs, num1, num2)
{
s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
if (s.length < 2)
{
  s = "0" + s;
}
return (s);
}
function CountBack(myDiv, secs)
{
var DisplayStr;
var DisplayFormat = "%%D%% дней %%H%% часов %%M%% минут %%S%% секунд";
DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g,    Calcage(secs,86400,100000));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g,       Calcage(secs,3600,24));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g,       Calcage(secs,60,60));
DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g,       Calcage(secs,1,60));
if(secs > 0)
{
  document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = DisplayStr;
  setTimeout("CountBack('" + myDiv + "'," + (secs-1) + ");", 990);
}
else
{
  document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "Auction Over";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: `new Date("20/12/2016 16:00 PM -0400") == Invalid Date`

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема заключается в неправильном формате даты. При вызове функции

```
StartCountDown("clock1","20/12/2016 16:00 PM -0400")
```

в параметр `myTargetDate` приходит значение `"20/12/2016 16:00 PM -0400"` и при выполнении `var dthen   = new Date(myTargetDate);` переменная `dthen` получает значение `"Inavlid Date"`.

Далее все операции в которых участвует эта переменная возвращают `NaN`.

И так как **все** операции сравнения `NaN` возвращают `false` в условии

```
if(secs > 0)
```

всегда выбирается ветка `else`

```
document.getElementById(myDiv).innerHTML = "Auction Over";
```

Подробнее о поддерживаемых форматах можно почитать в справке: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)